# PLACEHOLDER - Ernesto Llanes Perez' app

Tags: app, placeholder

The App is currently under development and / or only meant for private use.

When the author of this App is ready, they will update this post.

Comment: @RuhitGupta thanks for replacing the non-informational text here. However, the [template](https://stackapps.com/q/9481/34061) is a bit more than just plain text - see the HTML comments. Could you keep that in mind for next time? Thanks in advance!