# Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write. I submited this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions for stack apps post

Tags: support, app, placeholder

OAuth Domain mannubhai2006@gmail.com

Application Website: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ECqepVphS3Dds05zUJ8l0ylkQ9X15iUZ_iqhQCM3vfY/edit?usp=sharing

Application Icon (optional): ''

Stack Apps Post (optional): 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629357/applications-must-have-a-registered-stack-apps-post-to-write' # not able to add stack apps post and not sure how to

https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/edit/26725/submit

stack should accept my stack apps post on this link

Comment: Take care, if that's actually your real email.

Answer (score 1):

You need a non-deleted question on Stack Apps to allow for write-access under the given client-id.

So instead of:

> **Stack Apps Post (optional):** `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629357`

you can now use the very question here on Stack Apps that you asked:

> **Stack Apps Post (optional):** `https://stackapps.com/questions/9909`

So "Stack Apps Post" refers to a question on this very site. Questions or answers on any other site within the Stack Exchange Network are not eligible to be used as "Stack Apps Post" to unlock write-access.

We do allow placeholder posts for exactly that reason. See [Adjusting the question templates to better accommodate placeholders](https://stackapps.com/questions/9481/adjusting-the-question-templates-to-better-accommodate-placeholders) and [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) for guidance on such placeholder posts.